# How do I get slimv working with SBCL?

Tags: vim, common-lisp, slimv

I am trying to get slimv (latest version from hg) working with SBCL 1.2.2.
When I add `let g:slimv_impl="sbcl"` to `.vimrc` and try to let slimv start
a SWANK server the load fails with this error:

```
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   READ error during COMPILE-FILE:
;   
;     Symbol "CODE-TRACE-TABLE-OFFSET-SLOT" not found in the SB-VM package.
;   
;       Line: 1406, Column: 70, File-Position: 55999
;   
;       Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM
;                 for "file ~/.vim/bundle/slimv/slime/swank-sbcl.lisp"
;                 {1002D56253}>
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
;   printed 1 note
; compilation aborted after 0:00:00.267
```

A quick google led me to suspect that the bundled SLIME version is too old,
so I got the latest release (2.10) and replaced the `slime` folder with it.
Now starting and connecting to the lisp process seems to work fine, but the
REPL is broken. I can enter code but pressing return does not output a result
and does not print the prompt again. `Eval-Defun` etc. do not seem to work either.

My VIM is version 7.4, compiled with Python (2.7) support. slimv is working fine
when using CLISP.

Comment: Slimv author here. Yes, the bundled SLIME version is too old, I'm planning to replace it with the latest one. There is a new bug reported [here](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/issues/13) about a broken call to `:create-repl`. Please check if making the adjustments suggested in the bug report solves the problem (changing `swank:create-repl` => `swank-repl:create-repl` and `swank:listener-eval` => `swank-repl:listener-eval` in `ftplugin/swank.py`).

Comment: That did it. Thank you for your help, and of course for writing slimv :D

Comment: I thank you for the test. I'm going to fix this problem soon.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I wrote a workaround in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300169/how-do-i-get-slimv-working-with-sbcl#comment41275520_26300169), but I've just fixed the problem in slimv as well. I have also updated the bundled Slime to the latest version, see commits [3ebb6d8](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/commit/3ebb6d85c80f79df54a311d1c9243a867c169352) and [d26110f](https://github.com/kovisoft/slimv/commit/d26110f7fe9ff302d9a46a600e6366792fff0782) on github. So I hope everything is working fine now. Please let me know if you still experience any problems using slimv.